# wrong current url in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a google chrome extension that is shown onclick in a popup. There is a context menu with some options that need the current / active tab url. The extension has a problem described below.

**Old code:**

```
function menuCallback(info, tab) {

var currentUrl = tab.url;
```

With old code: If you right-click inside the popup, the current url returned is "chrome-extension..." and so on.

**New Code: (i tried to fix the issue with)**

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
    function(tabs){
        currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
    }
);
```

This works, as it returns the tab url even if the click comes from inside the popup. But if i have like 10 open tabs and switch between two, always the old one is returned. For example i'm at google.de first, url returned is google.de. Now i switch to an already open tab like "heise.de" and right-click, it's still google.de. Next attempt / try the url is correct.

Comment: your `new code` is correct way to get reference of active tab in current window, and share code how you are making a call to new code(I assume you are aware of async nature of chrome api.*).

Comment: Thanks very much, Sudarshan. I kind of jumped in this project and didn't know about the async thing. Made it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `onUpdated` listener.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(doSomething);
```

Which gives you the tabId, changeInfo and tab metadata. You then can do as you please:

```
var doSomething = function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  var match = /http:\/\/www.google.com/.exec(tab.url);
  if(match && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
       ... do something ...
  } 
}
```

EDIT: After reading again your question, what you probably want is the **onHighlighted** [event listener](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#events). It returns an object with an array of `tabsIds` and the `window` as soon as you select a tab.

```
chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(o) { tabId = o.tabIds[0]; })
```

You can then use `get` in order to obtain more information about that specific tab.

```
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) { ... })
```

I'm leaving the `onUpdated` code in case anyone wants the tab information whenever a page changes.

Comment: Thanks! But this function only seems to be called if a new tab is loaded and finished loading. When i have many open tabs and switch between 1 or 2, the function doesnt get called again.

Comment: You can use `changeInfo.status == 'loading'` or just don't use it at all.

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga: OP is asking to get reference of an active tab in a window out of all completely loaded tabs, when he switches among tabs, where your `changeInfo` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [query parameters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) the simplest solution to finding the URL of the active tab in the currently focused window would be the following.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    var currentURL= tab.url;
    alert(currentURL); // this should give you current url.
}
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.getSelected is deprecated